# A "special" case of merging in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I am a quite unexperienced R user facing the following problem:

I would like to merge two data tables dt1 and dt2.
dt1 contains 1 variable entitled Assessment.
dt2 contains 2 variables entitled ID and Frequency.
Now, I would like to have also the Assessment observations in dt2.

For simplicity, consider this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(c("perfect", "perfect", "okay", "unsufficient", "good", "good", "okay", "perfect"))
colnames(dt1) <- "Assessment"

dt2 <- data.table(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(1,3,1,1,1,1)))
colnames(dt2) <- c("ID", "Frequency")
```

Hence, dt1 looks like that:

| Assessment |
| --- |
| perfect |
| perfect |
| okay |
| unsufficient |
| good |
| good |
| okay |
| perfect |

dt2 looks like that:

| ID | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

My aim would be to get something like:

| ID | Frequency | Assessment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | perfect |
| 2 | 3 | perfect;okay;unsufficient |
| 3 | 1 | good |
| 4 | 1 | good |
| 5 | 1 | okay |
| 6 | 1 | perfect |

I do not have any idea how to come here and would appreciate each help very much! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your real scenario would be possible to have ID in dt1? If so is possible to join both data.frames?

Comment: @ViníciusFélix Thank you for your answer, but this is not possible

Comment: But then how would we know that for the ID number 2 we have 3 Assessments

Comment: From the Frequency variable. This means that for ID 2 there should be 3 Assessments and for all other IDs one Assessment. Moreover, the Assessments in dt1 are already in the right order. So, ID 1 needs the first assessment, ID 2 needs the second, third, and forth assessment, and so on. Sorry for beig not precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt1 %>% 
  bind_cols(
    dt2 %>% 
      uncount(Frequency) 
  ) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Assessment = paste0(Assessment,collapse = ";"))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     ID Assessment               
  <dbl> <chr>                    
1     1 perfect                  
2     2 perfect;okay;unsufficient
3     3 good                     
4     4 good                     
5     5 okay                     
6     6 perfect
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the right order, as you say in OP, you can `rep.int` the IDs according to their frequencies.

```
dt2[dt1[, list(Assessment=toString(Assessment)), by=list(ID=with(dt2, rep.int(ID, Frequency)))], on=.(ID)]
#    ID Frequency                  Assessment
# 1:  1         1                     perfect
# 2:  2         3 perfect, okay, unsufficient
# 3:  3         1                        good
# 4:  4         1                        good
# 5:  5         1                        okay
# 6:  6         1                     perfect
```

or

```
dt2[dt1[, list(Assessment=list(Assessment)), by=list(ID=with(dt2, rep.int(ID, Frequency)))], on=.(ID)]
#    ID Frequency                Assessment
# 1:  1         1                   perfect
# 2:  2         3 perfect,okay,unsufficient
# 3:  3         1                      good
# 4:  4         1                      good
# 5:  5         1                      okay
# 6:  6         1                   perfect
```

The difference is, in second version `Assessment` is a list column.

**Note:** if `dt2` doesn't contain anything else, there's no need to merge anymore and it simplifies to

```
dt1[, list(Assessment=toString(Assessment)), by=list(ID=with(dt2, rep.int(ID, Frequency)))]
#    ID                  Assessment
# 1:  1                     perfect
# 2:  2 perfect, okay, unsufficient
# 3:  3                        good
# 4:  4                        good
# 5:  5                        okay
# 6:  6                     perfect
```